# How to fetch elements from an array stored in a php file and display them as text on an HTML page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a page that's called **index.html** and a php file called **topics.php**. The **topics.php** looks like this:

```
<?php
$topics = array("Technology", "Badminton", "Languages");
echo(json_encode($topics));
?>
```

I want that these topics are listed on **index.html** (and since the index.html page will also have a form called ***Submit/Create a topic***, the $topics array would be updated with additions and I want the list on index.html to be updated automatically. This shall look like:

```
 - Technology
 - Badminton
 - Languages
 - Writing
 - Art
```

on the index.html web page. (Assuming Writing and Art have been added later through the form)

I must use **ajax/jquery** and data transfer should preferably occur in **json** format. How to go about it?

Comment: 1. Since you want to process this PHP array in your *index* page, change *index.html* to *index.php* page. 2. If you want to dynamically build this topics array, I'd recommend you to create one MySQL table and keep those topics in that table, because in this way it'd be easier for you insert, update and delete topics.

Comment: I tried the index.php alternative and it definitely works, however this being a university assignment the instructions explicitly state that it must be an html page hosted on my university php server with the url www.xyz.ac.uk/name.surname/index.html . So the php option is ruled out. Thanks for the help though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use loops to loop through the array and print the un-ordered list in html along with the array elements.

```
<?php
  $topics = array("Technology", "Badminton", "Languages");
?>
<html>
<body>
    <ul>
        <?php 
            foreach($topics as $v)
            {
                echo '<li>'.$v.'</li>';
            }
        ?>

    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the simplest solution to dynamically print list elements.

Comment: I have already exactly the same thing, but the constraint is that it's my university summative and the instructions explicitly state that the url has to be www.xxxx.ac.uk/name.surname/index.html. So I can't really go for this.

Comment: Thank you for the help though :)